# Is there a way to attach bindings to a setContentView activity

Tags: android, android-databinding

Currently if I want attach bindings I do

```
DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.main_activity);
```

I'm having troubles with a custom third-party Activity that needs to call

```
setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
```

How I can attach binding to an activity where the layout was set with `setContentView`

Comment: what is that library

Comment: If it is custom third party activity, what is the need of using binding in that?

Comment: @skadoosh this is the library [Dragger](https://github.com/ppamorim/Dragger)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to inflate you layout first, call `setContentView(inflatedView)` and set the DataBinding:

```
/* I don't know if passing 'null' as parent breaks something in your layout, I tested it in 
   mine and it did work.*/

View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null); 
setContentView(rootView);
ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.bind(rootView);
```

Comment: This is working for data binding but now I'm having a different issue the third-party activity are behaving like a regular one

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand you - did this solve your question?